# Is the caching issue in displaying the count on review button finally fixed?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, design

Today I noticed that my review button was being displayed in a different manner than it usually does. This is how it looks today:

[image]

Notice that there is no count on the button. Individual queue stats are loaded once I click the button.

Is this going to solve the [long standing count-caching issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238698/does-the-review-queue-page-show-only-reviews-requiring-your-action-does-it-diff/238699#238699)?

Comment: My guess is that because the overall count is no longer shown on the icon, the actual count can be pulled with less worry about caching because it's only ever calculated when someone expands the dropdown.

Comment: @DavidG That's my assumption too. Just seeking the official confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this has been confirmed by Shog. Quoting [him](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238698/does-the-review-queue-page-show-only-reviews-requiring-your-action-does-it-diff/238699?noredirect=1#comment954086_238699):

> Well... It's a fix, @NSNoob. It ain't ideal; the ideal implementation
>   would light up the indicator when - and only when - there are tasks
>   that you need to do when you haven't been reviewing for a while. But
>   it is an improvement: there's a delay, no bogus number, and a check
>   for some reasonably-sane number of pending tasks.